# Phasor representation of voltage in frequency domain

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, waves, complex-numbers

In a text on application of electromagnetism in transmission line, there introduces a [phasor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor) for the voltage (in frequency domain)

$$\tilde{V}(x) = V^+e^{-i\beta x} + V^-e^{i\beta x.}$$

Here $V^+$ and $V^-$ are the amplitude of the incoming wave and reflected wave. My question is the exponential $e^{-i\beta x}$ and $e^{i\beta x}$ are already complex, so should $V^+$ and $V^-$ be real or complex? and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complex $V^+$ and $V^-$ (or in practice, just the reflected wave amplitude) represent the relative phase shift between the two signals.

Comment: Thanks. So the phase shift will be reflected in $V^+$ and $V^-$ instead of $\beta x$?

Comment: @user1285419: You're welcome.  Yes, $\beta x$ gives the phase characteristic of the wave as a function of position, but it has a fixed value of 0 at $x=0$.  A complex amplitude permits that value to be different.